# Create a Jenkins Matrix Job with parameters based on files present in folder or shell script output

Tags: bash, matrix, jenkins, properties

I am trying to create a Matrix Configuration job in Jenkins based on the files present in a directory on the host machine.

Effectively, if under the workspace directory we run `$(ls *.properties)` there are

```
a.properties
b.properties
c.properties
```

I want a Matrix configuration job to run using those 3 results as an axis property list.

I would prefer not to use a lightweight upstream task to collect the values and populate a property for the DynamicAxis plugin, but I have already tried this and can't figure out how to get the output of a bash script into one of the predefined properties anyway. At this point I'm happy for any suggestions on how this may be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [the groovy axis plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GroovyAxis)

> This plugin allows to have scriptable axes for Matrix Jobs. Groovy is
>   the scripting language being used.
>
> The script will have to return a list of strings and each of the
>   strings will be an element of the axis.

Which includes an example of exactly what you want

> Define an axis whose values are the files in the root directory:

```
def dir = new File('/')
def result = []
dir.eachFile {
   if (it.isFile()) {
      result += it.canonicalPath
   }
}

return result
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the file path from Jenkins parameter ? Trying to use `def resolver = context.build.buildVariableResolver;
  value = resolver.resolve("YOUR_PARAMETER")` is not working in groovyAxis plugin.

Comment: @NoamManos you need to do something like `if (context != null) def resolver = context.build.buildVariableResolver; ...` . Take a look at this https://gist.github.com/markhu/78c8fbe947d244de282a